# ios Swift: Passing data from tableView to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Suo.png)well this is my first time posting a  question so not to sure how it works. I am doing an assignment on swift. I am stuck at a point where I need to pass the data from tableview to viewcontroller. On my first ViewController, I have a list of data (Categories) coming from the database table and when the user clicks on any of the cell, it should go to the next viewcontroller the label becomes the heading. Please find my screen shot attached.

Thanks

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}    

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryList_TableViewCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.categoryLabel.text = maindata["NAME"] as? String
    return cell;

}
```

I tried using `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`  and `perparesegue` functions but not getting my head around.

can anyone can guide me.

Thanks a million in advance :)

[image: screenshot of the table]

Comment: please show us what you have try with `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`.

Comment: Are You moving with a segue to the next viewController? What is the identifier?

Comment: yes, i am moving with the segue to the next viewcontroller (subCategoryVC.swift). the name of the identifier is "catView".

Comment: Nirav D, I have taken the screenshot and edited my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to implement didSelectRow just to pass data through a segue. Assuming you're using Storyboards.

1. CTRL drag from the prototype TableViewCell in your storyboard to the ViewController you want to pass data to.
2. Choose Show for the segue type and give it an identifier
3. Do this in prepareForSegue:

   ```
   if segue.identifier == "catView" {
       if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
           let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController
           let value = values[indexPath.row]
           controller.catTitleRec = value["NAME"] as! String
   }
   ```

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. I tried to follow this solution but still giving an error " Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10ad710e0) to 'NSString' (0x10a378ab8). in my output console. 
  "

Comment: controller.catTitleRec = values[indexPath.row] as! String  . It prompted me to use as! String so i added and run the program. WHen i clicked on one of the cell it came back to xcode and showed me this error msg in my console

Comment: You can't cast a dictionary to a string, so try this:

Comment: `let value = values[indexPath.row]` `controller.catTitleRec = value["NAME"] as! String`

Comment: nighttalker, thanks a lot!!!! it works now.  Thanks once again for your time and effort :)

Comment: hey nighttalker, I have one more question to ask you :( . Now I am getting the data displayed on my destination VC, but still my data is not filtering. as you see in my screenshot, I have a group of categories displayed, if someone clicks on the cell,  in the destination VC it should sort all the sub catergories that falls into it. (for eg. if I click on PETS/ANIMALS, it has its sub-category such as Cat, dog, Cows). This data is coming from the database. To test this I ran the sql, and its fine. I just cant work this out here. Thanks in adv :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: mainData)
```

Then, in your `prepareForSegue` function do this:

```
let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewcontroller as! YourCustomViewController
destinationVC.yourObject = sender as! YourObject
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. As you say YourObject - it is the value of the cell (text) but I am not able to call that object, can you please help me how can i call that object. thanks

Comment: Ok then you just have to make it a String. `sender as! String`. And in your destination VC you will need to declare some variable where you can put that value in.

Comment: in my destination VC i have set the variable. I tried doing  sender as! String but gives an error 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: this is what i have:

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("catView", sender: maindata)
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SubCatergory_ViewController
        destination!.catTitleRec = sender as! String
    }

Comment: Please update your question with the added source code instead of posting it to the comments, it's very hard to read :). Put a `print("sender value: \(sender)")` at the beginning of your `prepareForSegue` function and take a look at the console output. It should show you the type of the object

Comment: I am see the value in the console and it shows " sender value: Optional(OTHER)  "

Comment: sorry I mean I am getting this output in the console " sender value: Optional({
    NAME = "OTHERS";   "

Comment: Hi, if i am using  sender as! String, I am getting this output in my console " 'mobTechAssignmet2.CategoryList_TableViewCell' (0x104036470) to 'NSString' (0x104476ab8). "

Comment: So it prints the whole object, right? What do you need in your destination VC? Just that one String or the whole object? Depending on that you need to do the proper cast.

Comment: i just need that one string name ( value of the cell) to be displayed on my next view controller